# If inside If in Informix stored proc

Tags: informix

In Informix stored Procedure I have some condition which goes like this :-

```
     If val1 > 0                   // 1st If
     Select count(*) of value from a table and stored it in a Variable say VALUE
     If VALUE > 0                  // 2nd If 
     perform UPDATE 
     ELSE                          // Intended ELSE for 2nd IF
     Perform Insert
     END IF
     ELSE                          // Intended ELSE for 1st IF 
     perform Operation X  
     END IF
```

Some how I see my `execution is always going in ELSE Intended for 1st IF` and this is creating a problem for me . Can SomeOne let me know How can I correct this or where am i
Going Wrong.
Regards

Answer (score 3):

The explicit keyword END IF means that the nesting of IF statements in SPL is unambiguous.  Translating and indenting your code yields:

```
 IF val1 > 0 THEN
     SELECT COUNT(*) INTO value FROM SomeTable;
     If VALUE > 0 THEN
         Perform UPDATE 
     ELSE
         Perform INSERT
     END IF
 ELSE 
     Perform Operation X  
 END IF
```

There is no way for there to be any ambiguity; there is no 'dangling else' problem because of the explicit END IF notation.

If the wrong code is being executed, then maybe you're being caught by 3-value logic and the behaviour of comparisons when one of the comparands is NULL.  For example, if `val1` is NULL, then the `perform Operation X` will always be executed because `val1 > 0` is `NULL > 0` which evaluates to NULL which is not TRUE so the ELSE clause is taken and Operation X is performed.

As [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16258197/15168) by [ceinmart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/469192/ceinmart), you can use `SET DEBUG FILE` and `TRACE ON` to debug what is happening as you execute the stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Include the commands bellow before the if.

```
set debug file to '/tmp/trace.out';
trace on ;
....
trace "Value of val1 ="||val1; 
trace "Value of VALUE = "||VALUE;
```

Run the procedure and check the output of the /tmp/trace.out file on SERVER where the database is.
To commands reference, use the online manual :  [TRACE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/informix/v121/index.jsp?tab=search&searchWord=trace) , [SET DEBUG FILE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/informix/v121/topic/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1112.htm)

Comment: A NULL in string concatenation yields a NULL string. It's a very good practice to use `TRACE "Value of val1 = " || NVL(val1, "NULL");`. Doubly so given Jonathan's diagnosis.